# Terrain height map generator

Tags: performance, image, perl, sqlite

I wrote a Perl script that implements the algorithm described in this
[article](http://www.stuffwithstuff.com/robot-frog/3d/hills/hill.html) to generate terrain height maps.  The idea is to raise a random hill \$i\$ of size \$r_i\$ centered at point \$(x_i, y_i)\$, such that the height at point \$(x, y)\$ is

$$ z = r_i^2 - ((x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2) $$

The resulting terrain is the sum of many such hills, with some normalization and flattening.

The output of this program is a bunch of inserts into the database and a png. The only problem with it is that it has really bad performance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# mapgen.pl
# Henry J Schmale
# August 16, 2015
# Generates a height map

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Image::Magick;
use constant {
    MAX_X   =>  2000,
    MAX_Y   =>  2000,
    MAX_R   =>  1075,
    MIN_R   =>  100,
    NUM_HILLS => 250
};

my @heightmap;

makemap();

sub makemap {
    #init heightmap to 0
    for(my $i = 0 ; $i < MAX_Y; $i++){
        my @arr;
        for(my $j = 0; $j < MAX_X; $j++){
            $arr[$j] = 0;
        }
        $heightmap[$i] = \@arr;
    }

    # Start adding hills
    for(my $i = 0; $i < NUM_HILLS; $i++){
        makehill(int(rand(MAX_X)), int(rand(MAX_Y)), int(rand(MAX_R) + MIN_R));
    }
    # normallize
    my $maxvalue = 0;
    for(my $x = 0; $x < MAX_X; $x++){
        for(my $y = 0; $y < MAX_Y; $y++){
            if($heightmap[$x][$y] > $maxvalue){
                $maxvalue = $heightmap[$x][$y];
            }
        }
    }
    for(my $x = 0; $x < MAX_X; $x++){
        for(my $y = 0; $y < MAX_Y; $y++){
            $heightmap[$x][$y] /= $maxvalue;
        }
    }
    # Flatten
    for(my $x = 0; $x < MAX_X; $x++){
        for(my $y = 0; $y < MAX_Y; $y++){
            $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];
            $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];
            $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];
        }
    }
    # Dump to file
    dumpToImg();
    dumpToDb();
}

sub makehill {
    my ($x1, $y1, $r) = @_;
    my $z;
    for(my $x = $x1 - $r; $x < ($x1 + $r); $x++){
        for(my $y = $y1 - $r; $y < ($y1 + $r); $y++){
            my $dx = $x - $x1;
            my $dy = $y - $y1;
            $z = ($r * $r) - (($dx * $dx) + ($dy * $dy));
            if($z > 0 and $x > 0 and $y > 0){
                $heightmap[$x][$y] += $z;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub dumpToDb {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=server.sqlite",'','')
            or die DBI::errstr;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO map_heights(lat_pt, long_pt, z_pt)".
                            "VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
    for(my $x = 0; $x < MAX_X; $x++){
        for(my $y = 0; $y < MAX_Y; $y++){
            $sth->execute($x, $y, $heightmap[$x][$y]);
        }
    }
    $dbh->disconnect();
}

sub dumpToImg {
    my $im = Image::Magick->new;
    my $junk = MAX_X.'x'.MAX_Y;
    print $junk."\n";
    $im->Set(size => $junk);
    $im->ReadImage('canvas:white');
    warn "$im" if "$im";
    for(my $x = 0; $x < MAX_X; $x++){
        for(my $y = 0; $y < MAX_Y; $y++){
            my $z = $heightmap[$x][$y];
            my @pixel = ($z, $z, $z);
            $im->SetPixel(x=>$x, y=>$y, color=>\@pixel);
        }
    }
    my $x = $im->Write('heightmap.png');
    warn "$x" if "$x";
}
```

Comment: What is your goal for putting the map into a database? Merely to retrieve it again? Or do you plan to run SQL queries to analyze the topology?

Comment: @200_success Retrieval, and analyzing the topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing number of nested loops and using native perl foreach loop which generally perform better would be a good start in optimization,

```
# ... 
my @heightmap;
my $maxvalue = 0;

# init image
my $im = Image::Magick->new;
my $junk = MAX_X .'x'. MAX_Y;
print $junk, "\n";
$im->Set(size => $junk);
$im->ReadImage('canvas:white');
warn $im if $im;

# init prepared sql insert
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=server.sqlite",'','')
    or die DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO map_heights(lat_pt, long_pt, z_pt) VALUES(?, ?, ?)")
    or die $dbh->errstr;

makemap();

sub makemap {

    # Start adding hills
    for my $i (0 .. NUM_HILLS-1) {
        makehill(int(rand(MAX_X)), int(rand(MAX_Y)), int(rand(MAX_R) + MIN_R));
    }

    for my $x (0 .. MAX_X-1) {
        for my $y (0 .. MAX_Y-1) {
            # init to 0
            $heightmap[$x][$y] //= 0;

            $heightmap[$x][$y] /= $maxvalue;
            $heightmap[$x][$y] **= 8;
            # $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];
            # $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];
            # $heightmap[$x][$y] *= $heightmap[$x][$y];

            my $z = $heightmap[$x][$y];
            $im->SetPixel(
              x => $x,
              y => $y,
              color => [ ($z) x 3 ],
            );
            $sth->execute($x, $y, $z);
        }
    }
    # Dump to file

    # dumpToImg();
    my $x = $im->Write('heightmap.png');
    warn $x if $x;

    # dumpToDb();
    $dbh->disconnect();
}

sub makehill {
    my ($x1, $y1, $r) = @_;

    for my $x ($x1 - $r .. ($x1 + $r)-1) {
        ($x > 0) or next;

        for my $y ($y1 - $r .. ($y1 + $r)-1) {
            ($y > 0) or next;

            my $dx = $x - $x1;
            my $dy = $y - $y1;
            my $z = ($r * $r) - (($dx * $dx) + ($dy * $dy));
            if ($z > 0) {
                $heightmap[$x][$y] += $z;
                if ($heightmap[$x][$y] > $maxvalue) {
                    $maxvalue = $heightmap[$x][$y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two things right off the bat that may help:

1. Calculate `$maxvalue` inside `makehill()` so you don't have to calculate it after
2. Do the normalization and flattening in 1 pass. Also, you can do the flattening in a single function call. You're basically raising each value to the 8th power, so use the power function. I don't know `perl` real well, but it's usually called `pow()` and takes a value and an exponent.

The other thing that looks problematic is setting each individual pixel through a function call. Is there any way to pass a buffer of memory to ImageMagick? If so, it would probably faster to do that.